# What is the difference between English besides English (UK) and English (US)?

Tags: differences, dialects

If you go to some sites, or to region settings in say Windows, you get many choices of English, I know the difference of spelling between English (UK) and English (US).

But what of English (France), English (Zimbabwe), etc? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least Australian English and Indian English with substantial differences to either British or US English. There is no "French English", although if you write English for a French speaking audience, you might avoid things that have different meaning in British and US English.

"Region settings" often include both language and things like currency and date format, so English (Zimbabwe) might just change the currency compared to either English (British) or English (US).